# Jenkins pipeline - How to retry in Stage , step and single command level

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have the following Jenkins pipeline that needs to grep a file - I know that it takes some time till the file is created. Is it possible to retry a single command, in my example is :

**env.LOG_STATUS = sh(script: "ssh ${params.zeek_server_username}@${params.zeek_server_ip} cat /data/zeek-data/logs/current/smtp.log | grep 1.1.1.2",returnStdout: true)**

BTW ,
how can I retry in step and stage level?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'zeek_nic_id_1', defaultValue: 'ens192', description: '')
        string(name: 'zeek_nic_id_2', defaultValue: 'ens224', description: '')
        string(name: 'zeek_server_ip', defaultValue: '1.1.1.1', description: '')
        string(name: 'zeek_server_username', defaultValue: 'user', description: '') 
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Verify if IP 1.1.1.2 can be found in SMTP logs ') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.LOG_STATUS = sh(script: "ssh ${params.zeek_server_username}@${params.zeek_server_ip} cat /data/zeek-data/logs/current/smtp.log | grep 1.1.1.2",returnStdout: true)
                    sh 'echo $LOG_STATUS'
                 }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Check out the [retry](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry-retry-the-body-up-to-n-times) step, it is exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you explain the connection between the desire for a retry, and the fact that the command takes some time ? What would the retry accomplish, in your thinking ?